# Equivalent of CGPoint with integers?

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, core-graphics

Cheers,

I like strict typing in C. Therefore, I don't want to store a 2D vector of floats if I specifically need integers. Is there an Apple-provided equivalent of `CGPoint` which stores data as integers?

I've implemented my type `Vector2i` and its companion function `Vector2iMake()` à la CGPoint, but something deep in me screams that Apple was there already.

---

Updating to explain.

I need a datatype that will store coordinates in a board game. These are most definitely integers. Same would be if I were to implement a tile-based turn based strategy, or a tile-based RPG.

Comment: Down-voting this is a bit harsh!

Comment: +1 It's a legitimate question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you happen to be representing your game board as objects stored in non-sparse nested arrays, then you may want to consider subclassing [NSIndexPath](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSIndexPath), or using it directly.

From the class reference:

> The NSIndexPath class represents the path to a specific node in a tree of nested array collections. This path is known as an index path.
>
> Each index in an index path represents the index into an array of children from one node in the tree to another, deeper, node.

Comment: Nice. I didn't think of this. With the `initWithIndexes:length:` method, it looks quite usable. I have to wait 37 more minutes before accept, but if nothing more Obj-C-ish comes around, I think this is the best way to move on.

Answer (score 7):

(to directly answer the question...)

I am not aware of a "NSIntegerPoint", but it wouldn't be difficult to make one:

```
struct NSIntegerPoint {
   NSInteger x;
   NSInteger y;
};
```

Along with stuff like:

```
CG_INLINE NSIntegerPoint
NSIntegerPointMake(NSInteger x, NSInteger y)
{
  NSIntegerPoint p; p.x = x; p.y = y; return p;
}

CG_INLINE bool
__NSIntegerPointEqualToPoint(NSIntegerPoint point1, NSIntegerPoint point2)
{
  return point1.x == point2.x && point1.y == point2.y;
}
#define NSIntegerPointEqualToPoint __NSIntegerPointEqualToPoint
```

Comment: Hi,

I have already implemented something along these lines. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 3):

According to iPhone Application Programming Guide, all provided points are float-based. And when you use them to work with the screen (eventually expecting integers), you should anyway use floats for independence from screen resolution and etc.

Comment: +1 Floats are used expressly because integers will not work across devices and throughout transforms. A CGPoint is less a fixed point than it is more like a two dimensional percentage of the display area. When you start transforming objects by scaling, rotating, skewing, etc the idea of a fixed point representing a single pixel on the screen disappears completely. You're left with nothing but relative location within the transformed region.

Comment: While your answer is valid, it does not address my question, since I do NOT intend to use this for graphical points -- I need integer vectors for things like coordinates in a board game. I certainly need `float`-based vectors for graphics, and use them extensively there. Updating question.

Comment: Ok. The answer is: "probably, not". And answer above is the explanation why.
Finally you can either define your own struct (as you made) or use something like NSIndexSet.

Answer (score 0):

You could use int vectors?

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vecLib/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002498-CH1g-TPXREF103

Comment: While it (obviously) exists on Mac OS X, the only relevant reference to iPhone I found does not come from Apple and in fact mentions veclib.framework being a private Apple framework.